# Where can I find an list of explained Event ID's for Windows Event Log? Which one corresponds to network state changed?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1, connection

Where can I find an list of explained Event ID's for Windows Event Log?

Which one corresponds to network state changed from "internet" to "limited connectivity"?

I am in need to reconnect automaticly after my network changes to "limited" because of some unknown issue. This only happens to my laptop and only at home: after some time being connected to my network my network becomes "limited", I have to reconnect to gain my internet access again. I tried all methods from updating drivers to changing all possible configurations to uninstalling programs to cleaning old drivers to messing with registry to resetting the router to factory settings to messing with the router etc

None have helped the issue, after a random amount of time, sometimes hours, sometimes minutes, while connected to my home network, I get "limited connectivity" out of nowhere. just while browsing the net.

So I made a shortcut on the taskbar with this command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\netsh.exe wlan connect ssid=WLANGZX name=WLANGZX
```

when I click it I have internet again, but now I want to automate the process where this command will run when my network disconnects or changes state from internet to limited.

Which event ID corresponds to this in the event log? Where can I find a list with explainations of each event? It's really impossible to find anything on the windows Event Log and Task scheduler :(

Comment: Have you tried to search the Internet? What events are in the Event Viewer now? Try using a command prompt to run `ipconfig /flushdns`. Tell me if that helps.

Comment: Tried serching, millions of events but none with "network state changed to limited", command doesn't help.